# Monodeveloper run current project

Tags: mono, monodevelop

How can I make Mono Developer to RUN (**CTRL+F5**) the current project I'm on, in a solution with more than 1. In the solutions Startup Options you can only choose to RUN specific project or multiple at the same time.
Is there an option to run "Current Selection" like in Visual Studio ?

Comment: You should probably open bug/feature request at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ to support Ctrl+F5

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution window you can right click the project and select either **Run Item** or **Start Debugging Item**.

Run Item will run without the debugger, whilst Start Debugging Item will run it with the debugger.